# Set Admin User's Password Hash Directly

Tags: magento

I have an existing `admin_user` that I'm basically migrating to an additional `admin_user` record, and I want to set the password hash for the new record with the value from the old record.

Because `_beforeSave` hooks setPassword() and encrypts it, it doesn't seem possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was in the process of writing this question, when I figured out how to solve it, so I'll go ahead and post my own answer here, in case it helps anyone else.

Looks like you need to overload the `Mage_Admin_Model_User` class to do this.  Since you'll probably be loading the class directly and calling the method to set the password, you probably won't need to worry about rewrites or event observing.

Here's how I did it:

```
class Me_Mymodule_Model_Admin_User extends Mage_Admin_Model_user
{
    protected function _beforeSave()
    {
        parent::_beforeSave();

        if ($this->getPasswordHash()) {
            $this->setData('password', $this->getPasswordHash());
        }
    }
}
```

And then, to change it, do the following.  In my case, I did this within a custom migration script that I wrote.

```
// This just sets the "password_hash" data on the model which has no function other
// than to be converted to the "password" value in the _beforeSave() above.
$adminUser = Mage::getModel('mymodule/admin_user')->load($id);
$adminUser->setPasswordHash('insert password hash here')->save();
```

The `setPasswordHash()` and `getPasswordHash()` methods are regular Magento magic getters / setters, so they don't need to be defined anywhere.

UPDATE: Don't downvote for answering own question, it's [encouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/should-i-not-answer-my-own-questions).

Comment: Where did you put that `setPasswordHash()` call? (+1 for the humoUrous welcome to yourself)

Comment: Haha thanks!  Thought I was gonna get flamed for being ridiculously cheesy :)  Also, interesting that someone else actually was interested in this, I was sure I'd be pretty much the only one at least for a while :).  Well, if you mean where did I *call* it from, it was from a custom migration script.  If you mean where did I define it, it's just a regular magic setter.  I'll update the answer to reflect.

Comment: Aaaaand, there goes the flaming.  Any explanation on the downvote?  Thanks.

Comment: I think the reason you might be down voted is due to how quickly you asked and answered your own question, practically in the same breath.  Might come across bad and you are just looking to gain reputation opposed to helping people out??  Just my thoughts on subject as other people will undoubtedly think differently.  But thats part of good thing of stack overflow: everyone entitled to their opinion, good or bad and community decides whats useful by voting.

Comment: I don't think you need to keep your mouth shut, whatever happen, all I care is getting new information :)

Comment: Ya guess not.  In the end I received more points for upvotes than negatives for downvotes, so I guess SO system for dealing with the trolls is working.